# Toggle switch for Model field Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I'm trying to implement a slider checkbox that automatically updates a field in my Post column.

Here's my css

```
 .toggle-checkbox:checked {
    @apply: right-0 border-green-400;
    right: 0;
    border-color: #68D391;
  }
  .toggle-checkbox:checked + .toggle-label {
    @apply: bg-green-400;
    background-color: #68D391;
  }
```

And this is my toggle button component

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire\Admin\Table;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Livewire\Component;

class Published extends Component
{
    public Model $model;
    public string $field;
    public bool $isPublished;

    public function mount()
    {
       $this->isPublished = (bool) $this->model->getAttribute($this->field);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.admin.table.published');
    }

    public function updating($field, $value)
    {
        $this->model->setAttribute($this->field, $value)->save();
    }

 
}
```

This is my blade for the toggle button

```
<div>
    <div class="relative inline-block w-10 mr-2 align-middle select-none transition duration-200 ease-in bg-red-300">
        <input wire:model="isPublished"  type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle" class="toggle-checkbox absolute block w-6 h-6 rounded-full bg-white border-4 appearance-none cursor-pointer" />
        <label for="toggle" class="toggle-label block overflow-hidden h-6 rounded-full bg-gray-300 cursor-pointer"></label>
    </div> 
</div>
```

This is the parent component for the toggle button

```
@foreach ($values as $value)
    <td class="px-4 py-3">
         @livewire('admin.table.published', ['model' => $value, 'field' => 'status'], key($value->id))                     
    </td>
@endforeach
```

mount method seems to work fine, but whenever I try the updating method, it updates a different ID. Can anyone help? Thanks!

I'm using Php 7.3 ; Laravel 8.75; livewire 2.10

Comment: Seems rather overkill to make an entire component for this, why can't you implement the logic in the parent component? You can just use a `$toggle()` in the blade and a lifecycle hook in the component to do the same thing.

Comment: @Qirel I want this component to be reusable.

Found the issue. 

Issue is with blade for the toggle button.
Need to have unique ID <input wire:model="isPublished" name="{{$uniqueID}}" .. >
<label for="{{$uniqueID}}">